# samba share from Ubuntu VM fails with 'force user'

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, macosx

I have two ubuntu VM's (server running in VirtualBox, as development machines). The older box (ubuntu 12.04 LTS) is running samba just fine and all shares work well. 
When making a new machine, I copied the share information (but not the whole config file), to a new box (ubuntu 14.04 LTS), but many of the shares aren't working.

This share IS working on old and new:

```
[username]
path = /home/username
available = yes
valid users = username
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
force user = username
force group = username
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
hide dot files = no
follow symlinks = no
```

This share fails on the newer ubuntu 14.04 LTS (It's the same as above, but different 'force user/group':

```
[etc]
path = /etc
available = yes
valid users = username
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
force user = root
force group = root
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
hide dot files = no
follow symlinks = no
```

I have other shares that I 'force user = www-data' in a similar manner that also fail.

What I see (from osx) when I try to connect is: 
"The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “etc” can’t be found."
(I have no windows boxes to test with).

PS: The smb.conf is basically 'vanilla' otherwise: I have made no edits outside the shares themselves.

I have had a quick look at the logs, and the only thing that seems to get logged is in log.workstation:

```
[2014/07/27 09:02:06.173271,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4094(check_usershare_stat)
  check_usershare_stat: file /var/lib/samba/usershares/ owned by uid 0 is not a regular file
```

Any help in working out where to start solving this would be appreciated. Obviously, it has something to do with the 'force user' and 'force group'...but apart from that I don't know where to look.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I was struggling with a similar problem and this led me straight to double checking my group permissions. Lo and behold! A quick adjustment to group permissions and I'm up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across [this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/368342) which gave me the clue that I needed to add 'root' to the list of valid users.

The two shares which previous weren't working, now are. I added 'www-data' and 'root' respectively next to the 'valid users':

```
[sites]
path = /home/username/sites
available = yes
valid users = username,www-data
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
force user = www-data
force group = www-data
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
hide dot files = no
follow symlinks = no
;wide links = no

[etc]
path = /etc
available = yes
valid users = username,root
#guest ok = yes
#guest only = yes
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
force user = root
force group = root
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
hide dot files = no
follow symlinks = no
```

Anyways. This answer is for anyone else who might stumble across the same problem.
(No, I have no idea why it *used* to work, but broke on upgrade)